# How to trace ADO calls

Tags: windows, vb6, ado

Friends, Is there a tool available to trace all sql statements passed between ADO (legacy vb6) (NOT ADO.NET) and database server? Appreciate your help

Comment: What database are you using? Many databases will have a profiler that will help with this.

Comment: Microsoft SqlServer. Can't turn on the profiler at PROD db.

Comment: What version? The newer versions have lightweight tracing capabilities.

Comment: Turning the profiler on SqlServer is out of reach. No access. Is there any other way other than this approach?

Comment: If at the bottom most layer your database calls land on a ODBC driver they you could use ODBC tracing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711020%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you already seen this free (as in beer) [Statement Tracer for ADO](http://www.aboves.com/products/statement_tracer_for_ado/) app by some Above Software? From program site:

> Solution for monitoring SQL queries to Microsoft® ActiveX® Data
>   Objects (ADO) data sources.
>
> - Monitoring any number of applications.
> - Tracing ADO queries in real time.
> - Enabling and disabling monitoring at any moment.

Frankly, I never used or heard about it before. But quick test with VB6 ADO app vs. SQL Server 2008 Express looks good: the tool did capture connection string from ADODB.Connection.Open() and SQL statement text from ADODB.Connection.Execute().

Comment: Thanks for your help. Tried to download and run. Unfortunately this tool freeze at 'Start'. Any advise. Thanks.